# Put string into console, with ability edit

Tags: c++, string, windows

What function in C++ puts string into console, with ability edit? I have such state of console: [image]

After work of needed function I want to see this:

[image]

but not this:

[image]

Comment: Using standard functionality there's no way to make it. I don't think there's any [console function in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) to do exactly what you want according to your images. You could do it if you handle keys and editing yourself, but not with the standard prompt.

Comment: CMD is a program that uses the console. It isn't the console. Please remove CMD tags as your question has nothing to do with CMD.

Comment: You could make a program that presses the keys for you, cmd window needs to be focused though

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done natively on the terminal, you have to do it in your control flow.

A little example

```
string text("Hello, World")
cout << text;
char x = getch();
while (x != '\n') {             //loop breaks if you press enter
    if (x == 127 || x == 8) {   //for backspace(127) and delete(8) keys
        cout << "\b \b";        //removes last character on the console
        text.erase(text.size() - 1);
    }
    else {
        cout << x;
        text.append(x);
   }
    x = getch();
}
```

`"\b"` is nondestructive backspace. i.e it moves the cursor backwards but doesn't erase.
`"\b \b"` is destructive backspace.

Comment: This might allow the user to edit what's displayed, but it won't be sent in as input when he presses return.

Comment: @Barmar I just showed him an example, OP can manipulate the string by appending and erasing. Edited the code.